# C#. How to avoid double click when I need single click

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a windows form application. Creating a UI for some service. What is happening is when I created the application there are various buttons on which a single click should work to get and set the value but after the completion of code all those buttons are reacting on double click.
when we apply some break point and test, values get and set in single click only but during run-time it need double click. Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you please include a sample code that react like that?

Comment: I am sorry but it includes the whole code. when I completed this code then its started reacting in double click.

I am getting and setting the value on CAN bus.
initially when we have to get and  set the signal value and when the value was of double type everything went right. But when the value type changed to object type it started recation on double click.

Comment: Some snippets can speak more that your words. and that will be more clear for us

Comment: or a simple screen capture will explain better. Right now it is difficult understanding your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by writing a piece of code.
Just activated the button on first click.

bool firstClick = true;
{if(firstClick)    {    button.select();  //Activating the button    }    }

Thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN on how to use single-click only vs double-click only. Also, it states how you can handle events and differentiate between a single click and a double click.

The article uses boolean and timers to do that. You might need to use a `Dictionary<Button, boolean>` if you have multiple buttons. Hope it helps.

Here is the example if the link got down or removed for some reaosn:

> Handle the MouseDown event and determine the location and time span
>   between clicks using the appropriate SystemInformation properties and
>   a Timer component. Perform the appropriate action depending on whether
>   a click or double-click takes place. The following code example
>   demonstrates how this can be done.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private Rectangle hitTestRectangle = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle doubleClickRectangle = new Rectangle();
    private TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
    private Timer doubleClickTimer = new Timer();
    private ProgressBar doubleClickBar = new ProgressBar();
    private Label label1 = new Label();
    private Label label2 = new Label();
    private bool isFirstClick = true;
    private bool isDoubleClick = false;
    private int milliseconds = 0;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        label1.Location = new Point(30, 5);
        label1.Size = new Size(100, 15);
        label1.Text = "Hit test rectangle:";

        label2.Location = new Point(30, 70);
        label2.Size = new Size(100, 15);
        label2.Text = "Double click timer:";

        hitTestRectangle.Location = new Point(30, 20);
        hitTestRectangle.Size = new Size(100, 40);

        doubleClickTimer.Interval = 100;
        doubleClickTimer.Tick +=
            new EventHandler(doubleClickTimer_Tick);

        doubleClickBar.Location = new Point(30, 85);
        doubleClickBar.Minimum = 0;
        doubleClickBar.Maximum = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;

        textBox1.Location = new Point(30, 120);
        textBox1.Size = new Size(200, 100);
        textBox1.AutoSize = false;
        textBox1.Multiline = true;

        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { doubleClickBar, textBox1,
            label1, label2 });
    }

    // Detect a valid single click or double click.
    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Verify that the mouse click is in the main hit
        // test rectangle.
        if (!hitTestRectangle.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            return;
        }

        // This is the first mouse click.
        if (isFirstClick)
        {
            isFirstClick = false;

            // Determine the location and size of the double click 
            // rectangle area to draw around the cursor point.
            doubleClickRectangle = new Rectangle(
                e.X - (SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width / 2),
                e.Y - (SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height / 2),
                SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width,
                SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height);
            Invalidate();

            // Start the double click timer.
            doubleClickTimer.Start();
        }

        // This is the second mouse click.
        else
        {
            // Verify that the mouse click is within the double click
            // rectangle and is within the system-defined double 
            // click period.
            if (doubleClickRectangle.Contains(e.Location) &&
                milliseconds < SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
            {
                isDoubleClick = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void doubleClickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        milliseconds += 100;
        doubleClickBar.Increment(100);

        // The timer has reached the double click time limit.
        if (milliseconds >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
        {
            doubleClickTimer.Stop();

            if (isDoubleClick)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("Perform double click action");
                textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("Perform single click action");
                textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            // Allow the MouseDown event handler to process clicks again.
            isFirstClick = true;
            isDoubleClick = false;
            milliseconds = 0;
            doubleClickBar.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    // Paint the hit test and double click rectangles.
    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw the border of the main hit test rectangle.
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, hitTestRectangle);

        // Fill in the double click rectangle.
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, doubleClickRectangle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply identify single click and double using a timer. Here is the example

```
class Form1 : Form
{
       Timer timer;

       public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 500;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
       }
       private void App_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Clicks == 1)
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Stop();
                doubleClick();
            }
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            singleClick();
        }

        //Single click 
        public void singleClick()
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Single Click.");
        }

        //Double click 
        public void doubleClick()
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Double Click.");
        }
}
```

Comment: One more thing. I am not exactly sure that it works in double click only.
like if we click once and take some time say 2 secs and click again then also its taking.
Seems like form loading can be the issue.

Thanks for the solution i'll try these. but still take my this comment into consideration.